# Using ForEach and getting repeated elements in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, foreach

What I am trying to do is with an input add words into an array, then as you add the words I want them to be displayed in a list. So I did a function to render the list, and used a for each, then used that function inside the function that push the words into the array. The thing is that when you add the words the for each executes and duplicates all the words.

if you add tree as a word you get the output: tree

if you add rabbit you get the output  : tree, tree, rabbit

lets say you want to add falcon and you get: tree, tree, rabbit, tree, tree, rabbit, falcon

Here is the code

```
const renderPass = function (array, location) {
  array.forEach((element) => {
       let html = `<li class="k">${element}</li>`;

       location.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", html);
  });
};


const savingKeyWords = function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();

   keyWords.push(keyWord.value);
   renderPass(keyWords, listOfKeys);

   console.log(keyWords);

   clear(keyWord);
};
```

could you help me with this??

Comment: You're passing the whole array to `renderPass` on each addition, so you either empty the parent list before rendering each `li` or only pass the added word.

Comment: How do I empty the parent list befpre rendering each li??

Comment: `location.innerHTML = '';` Though if you do it this way it would be better to conatenate all the `li`s into a single string and then inserting it into the DOM once after your loop.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you seem to be using the same array defined in the global context over and over on every invocation.
Just create a new array when ever saving keywords is invoked.

```
const savingKeyWords = function (e) {
   let keyWords = [];

   e.preventDefault();

   keyWords.push(keyWord.value);
   renderPass(keyWords, listOfKeys);

   console.log(keyWords);

   clear(keyWord);
};
```

Answer (score -1):

I think 'keyWords' has to be replaced with 'keyWord.value' in here:

```
renderPass(keyWords, listOfKeys);
```

And

```
const renderPass = function (keyWord, location) {
       let html = `<li class="k">${keyWord}</li>`;
       location.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", html);
};
```

I hope this will be helpful for you. Thanks